# Random points with radius

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dilemma on an algorithm. I'm trying to generate 6 random positions that have a distance between them. My algorithm works, only to check the distance between the current point and the previous point. What I need is for the algorithm to verify the distance between all points and if the distance is less than the indicated value, it will generate a new position.

```
private void Generate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pos = PointsGenerator();
        Instantiate(point, pos, Quaternion.identity); // just to highlight the points on the screen
    }
}

private List<Vector3> Dist = new List<Vector3>();
private bool isOver = false;
private Vector3 PointsGenerator()
{
    Vector3 currentPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 oldPosition = Vector3.zero;
    float distance = 0f;
    do
    {
        currentPosition = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(minX, maxX), UnityEngine.Random.Range(minY, maxY), 0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < Dist.Count; i++)
        {
            distance = Vector2.Distance(currentPosition, Dist[i]);
            if (distance <= 4f)
            {
                isOver = true;
                break;
            }
            else
                isOver = false;
        }

    } while (isOver == true);
    Dist.Add(currentPosition);
    return currentPosition;
}
```

Thanks to all who will give advice.

Comment: You could store the points in a data structure (that best fits your needs) and compare them. However, wwhat is your goal with this?

Comment: I need these 6 points and not only have a distance between them, but also the distance from center + radius to be of value

Comment: Currently, your algorithm does not check if the points you placed on the screen has the required distance between them. you are only checking if the point created has the required distance from the previous point only. Suggest you store the points and do your checks after while adding them to data structure you store them in

Comment: Now I've modified the code above, it looks like it works, but it's not readable

Comment: Add all  generated points to a list and pass the current list to every call to `PointsGenerator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the question?

"I need these 6 points and not only have a distance between them, but also the distance from center + radius to be of value"

To achieve that, you will HAVE TO generate points that are on a sphere. For that, generate a (random if needed) center point of your sphere and define the radius.
Then, you need to use random spherical coordinates (radius, randomAngle1, randomAngle2). To convert those into cartesian coordinates, use

x = radius * cos(randomAngle1) * sin(randomAngle2)

y = radius * sin(randomAngle1) * sin(randomAngle2)

z = radius * cos(randomAngle1)

after that you can make the same algorithm as you already have to regenerate new points until they are far away from each other as well

Comment: `    Vector3 RandomPositionGenerator(Vector3 center, float radius, int a)
    {
        float ang = a;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + (radius + UnityEngine.Random.Range(2f, 4f)) * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y + (radius - 0.5f) * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z;
        return pos;
    }
`

Comment: this method is perfect for this problem...Thank everyone for your help :)))